# Checking duplicates in list from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

So I have written a code that generates a random list with random number of values. Then asks the user what number the user is looking for and if its in the list, it will tell the user what position in the list the number is in.

```
import random

a = [random.randint(1, 20) for i in range(random.randint(8, 30))]

a.sort()
print(a)


def askUser():

    n = input("What number are you looking for?")
    while not n.isdigit():
        n = input("What number are you looking for?")

    n = int(n)
    s = 0

    for numbers in a:
        if numbers == n:
            s += 1
            print("Number", n, "is located in the list and the position is:", (a.index(n)+1))
            # Something here to skip this index next time it goes through the loop
        else:
            pass
    if s == 0:
        print("Your number could not be found")


askUser()
```

I would like to add something that will skip the index it found first time and then look for the index of the duplicate if there is one.

Current result

```
[2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 10, 16, 19, 20, 20]
What number are you looking for?20
Number 20 is located in the list and the position is: 9
Number 20 is located in the list and the position is: 9
```

Desired result

```
[2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 10, 16, 19, 20, 20]
What number are you looking for?20
Number 20 is located in the list and the position is: 9
Number 20 is located in the list and the position is: 10
```

Comment: `a = random.choices(range(1, 20), k = random.randint(8, 30))` might be better then your list comp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for numbers in a:
```

To:

```
for i, numbers in enumerate(a):
```

And then change how you print the indices:

```
print("Number", n, "is located in the list and the position is:", (i+1))
```

Sample output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 16, 17, 17, 19, 19]
What number are you looking for? 8
Number 8 is located in the list and the position is: 9
Number 8 is located in the list and the position is: 10
Number 8 is located in the list and the position is: 11
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect, such a small thing but makes such a difference

Comment: Happy to help, by using `enumerate` here, you check for all indices in O(n) time instead of using `arr.index`, which only finds the first match.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel fancy you can convert some of your loops into list comprehensions:

```
def askUser():

    n = input("What number are you looking for?")
    while not n.isdigit():
        n = input("What number are you looking for?")

    n = int(n)

    # get a list of all indexes that match the number
    foundAt = [p+1 for p,num in enumerate(a) if num == n]

    if foundAt:
        # print text by creating a list of texts to print and decompose them
        # printing with a seperator of linefeed
        print( *[f"Number {n} is located in the list and the position is: {q}" for 
                 q in foundAt], sep="\n")
    else: 
        print("Your number could not be found")
```

Edit: as Chrisz pointed out `f""` format strings came with [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?) for Python 3.6 (wasn't aware :o/ ) - so for earlier 3.x Python would have to use

```
print( *["Number {} is located in the list and the position is: {}".format(n,q) for 
                 q in foundAt], sep="\n")
```

Comment: @chrisz PEP498 added :)

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this code using `numpy` to remove your loops.

```
a = np.array([random.randint(1,20) for i in range(random.randint(8,30))])
```

Then you can use `np.where` to determine if the user selected a value in your array `a` of random values:

```
idx_selections = np.where(a == n)[0]
```

Then you can handle if the user matched an answer or not:

```
if len(idx_selections) == 0:
    print("Your number could not be found")
else:
    for i in idx_selections:
        print("Number", n, "is located in the list and the position is:", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num =20

numlist = [2, 4, 8, 9, 10, 10, 16, 19, 20, 20]

for each in numlist:
    if num is each:
        print num
        print [i for i, x in enumerate(numlist) if x == num]
```

Comment: this is a python 2.x  answer -  the question is tagged with [tag:Python3]  - and you do not quite produce the wanted output ;)